# (xcode 6.1.1) ibtool failed with exit code 255

Tags: iphone, xcode6.1, ios8.1

I just install XCODE6.1.1 please help me on this issue. I will be thankful to you guys.
When I click on storyboard in XCODE 6.1.1 Xcode crash.

Command/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255

Comment: This is really an ill formed question... But anyway, I think I had the same problem one. Make sure that you have the correct iOS SDK versions installed at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs` and `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs`.

Comment: How can i check it installed correct IOS Sdk or Not

Comment: @fabian789 how can i check that

Comment: You can open the folder in Finder (with `CMD SHIFT G`) and check its contents. For example if there only is a subfolder called iPhoneOS8.1.sdk and you have selected iOS 7 as deployment target, you will get your error.

Comment: I solved this issue with different ways its un-usual. I just Drag Xcode in Application folder and then I restart the mac machine and open XCODE it work fine for me. Thanks for your valuable time and Answers.